# How to put some html before and after math when rendering using MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I am using MathJax 1.1 in my web site. I need to place some html before and after every math encountered by the processor (tex2jax in my case).

How can I do this?

- Should I register a callback?
- Should I use some options in configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was discussed on the [MathJax user's forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/licbps4hk4U).  You could try something like

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
  var TEX = MathJax.InputJax.TeX;
  var PREFILTER = TEX.prefilterMath;
  TEX.Augment({
    prefilterMath: function (math,displaymode,script) {
      math = "\\displaystyle{"+math+"}";
      return PREFILTER.call(TEX,math,displaymode,script);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

to add `\displastyle{` before and `}` after the mathematics.  You should put this script *before* the script that loads `MathJax.js`.

Answer (score 0):

If all your elements are in one parent element, you maybe could try this:

```
parent_element * {
width: auto;
}
```

It worked for me.